# how to use windows bash script to open a website with my username and password

Tags: http, bash

I like to write a windows bash script, test.bat to open a website, say www.test.com and provide my username and password at the same time.

Comment: Trying for the Enthusiast badge?

Comment: Probably, since Windows has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 1):

you can use autohotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a script to open website and enter your username/password. You can call the script from a .bat file (or even from bash). I did not understand why you want to use bash on windows.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) is an easy to write scripting language that would be great for this.